# AWS - java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'ip' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple Sprint boot application connecting to a mysql instance running on RDS in AWS cloud, as guided [here](http://carlmartensen.com/step-by-step-guide-to-building-and-deploying-a-database-backed-spring-boot-web-application-in-aws). I have created database instance and even I can connect to that mysql instance from my local mysql command line client. But when I am trying to connect it via application. I am always getting access denied exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myusr    '@'112.134.65.150' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:338) [spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getDefaultDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:198) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getOrDeduceDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:186) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getAdditionalProperties(JpaProperties.java:165) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.access$000(JpaProperties.java:126) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(JpaProperties.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.isInitializingDatabase(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:80) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:68) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1723) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1590) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.tharsan.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_07]java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'tharsan    '@'112.134.65.150' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:338) [spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getDefaultDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:198) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getOrDeduceDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:186) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getAdditionalProperties(JpaProperties.java:165) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.access$000(JpaProperties.java:126) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(JpaProperties.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.isInitializingDatabase(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:80) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:68) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1723) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1590) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at com.tharsan.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_07]
```

Following configurations are being used. Please advise me where am i doing wrong?

src/main/resources
application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://tharsan.cu5elr2o0k2v.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/<db-name>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

It cannot be permission issue, if so it should not be connected via mysql client as well.My question is why is it failing to connect it from application only? Am I missing any configurations ?

Comment: It cannot be permission issue, if so it should not be connected via mysql client as well.My question is why is it failing to connect it from application only? Am I missing any configurations ?

Comment: It is a permission issue I'm afraid.  Make sure that your user has access to the schema you're connecting to.

Comment: @TharsanSivakumar Can you please share how did you resolve it? I have the exact issue.

Answer (score -1):

the issue with your mysql username and password, check your mysql username and password first and also check that user having permission to access the database or not. provide the permission to user then connecation to the database.

Comment: I have used the same user name and password using mysql client and able to connect without any connectivity issues. But it arises for the application connectivity only?